# Form Builder validation in angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular-reactive-forms

my problem is when the user click the submit button without filling the mandatory field it must show error.I searched a lot i didnt find the solution am new to angular so anyone help me to solve the problem.

```html
<form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(myForm.value)" class="wpcf7-form">
  <p></p>
  <div formGroupName="serviceProviderDetail">
    <input formControlName="mobileStatus" placeholder="Please enter your name" type="hidden">
    <div formGroupName="user">
      <h6>First Name</h6>
      <p><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-name">
         <input formControlName="firstName" placeholder="Please enter your name" type="text"   name="firstName" id="firstName" [formControl]="firstName" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required"  >
          <div*ngIf="myForm.controls.serviceProviderDetail.controls.user.controls['firstName'].dirty && myForm.controls.serviceProviderDetail.controls.user.controls['firstName'].invalid   "class="alert alert-danger">
        Please enter a firstName
  </div>  
  </span>
      </p>
    </div>
    <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-warning" style="background-color:#FF812D;font-size:18px;width:200px;text-align: center;margin-left: 37%;margin-bottom: 5%;">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: check this [link](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/reactive) might help you

Comment: Where is the code building the reactive form controls?

Comment: No my requirement is submit button should not be enable but user tries to submit empty text it must show error.

Comment: But if you are disabling button, user cannot click submit unless the form is valid? so how could the user even click the button, if you want the validation message shown when user submits?

Answer (score 1):

Use required in input tag for more detailed validations **[formvalidator](http://www.formvalidator.net/)**

```html
<form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(myForm.value)" class="wpcf7-form">
  <p></p>
  <div formGroupName="serviceProviderDetail">
    <input formControlName="mobileStatus" placeholder="Please enter your name" type="hidden">
    <div formGroupName="user">
      <h6>First Name</h6>
      <p><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-name">
         <input required formControlName="firstName" placeholder="Please enter your name" type="text"   name="firstName" id="firstName" [formControl]="firstName" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required"  >
          <div*ngIf="myForm.controls.serviceProviderDetail.controls.user.controls['firstName'].dirty && myForm.controls.serviceProviderDetail.controls.user.controls['firstName'].invalid   "class="alert alert-danger">
        Please enter a firstName
  </div>  
  </span>
      </p>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" [disabled]="myForm.valid" class="btn btn-warning" style="background-color:#FF812D;font-size:18px;width:200px;text-align: center;margin-left: 37%;margin-bottom: 5%;">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: http://www.formvalidator.net/ it is angularjs but I need angular2 code @Nisal   Edu

Comment: @Thilagavathy sorry for the late reply try this https://medium.com/codingthesmartway-com-blog/angular-2-forms-tutorial-validation-efcd6756025b

Answer (score 0):

**use required="true"** in input field

```
<input formControlName="firstName" placeholder="Please enter your name" type="text"   name="firstName" id="firstName" [formControl]="firstName" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" required="true" >
```

Answer (score 0):

There were syntax issues and no code provided for the reactive form so I pared down the example to `firstName` and its error message. Guessing by the `formControlName` syntax, I assumed you're using [reactive forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) but let me know if you were trying to use template forms instead (e.g. ngModel).

1. **Flag the control as required:** Construct the `firstName` form control with `Validators.required`: `firstName: ['', Validators.required]`
2. **Disable submit while the form is invalid:** Submit button should be disabled when the form is *invalid*, not when it's valid: `<button [disabled]="myForm.invalid">Submit</button>`

I noted your question asked to show the message when the user *clicked the submit button with an empty string*. Instead, this approach disables the button when the form is invalid, as it will be when the user has not given a first name. If the user starts to give a first name and removes it, the error message will display reminding the user that the field is required (looks like you already had that working) and the button will disable again.

form.component.html:

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(myForm.value)">
  <div formGroupName="serviceProviderDetail">
    <h6>First Name</h6>
    <input formControlName="firstName" placeholder="Please enter your name" type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName">
    <div *ngIf="firstNameControl && firstNameControl.dirty && firstNameControl.invalid" class="alert alert-danger">
      First name is required
    </div>
    <button type="submit" [disabled]="myForm.invalid">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

form.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {

  myForm: FormGroup;

  get firstNameControl() {
    return this.myForm.controls['serviceProviderDetail'].controls['firstName'];
  }

  constructor(_fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.myForm = _fb.group({
      serviceProviderDetail: _fb.group({
        firstName: ['', Validators.required]
      })
    });
  }

  onSubmit(value) {
    console.log('Submit value:', value);
  }

}
```

Hope this helps. Here's a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/baVz7QVyw8frnolmTxks) to keep tinkering, let me know if this missed what you were asking.

Answer (score -1):

I have followed the same form control for my ionic project. PFB the registration page. Ignore the ionic tags and everything else is same and you can get idea for your Angular 2 project too. Declare the form and control variables in below typescript file

```
public signUpForm:FormGroup;
    public name:FormControl;
    public email:FormControl;
    public userId:FormControl;
    public faculty:FormControl;
    public terms:FormControl;
```

PFB the HTML file

```
<form [formGroup]="signUpForm" (submit)="register()">
            <ion-card>
                <ion-list class="login-data">
                    <ion-item [class.error]="!name.valid && name.touched">
                        <ion-input type="text" placeholder="Name" [(ngModel)]="registration.name" formControlName="name"></ion-input>
                    </ion-item>


                    <ion-item [class.error]="!email.valid && email.touched">
                        <ion-input  type="text" (blur)="triggerUserId()"  [(ngModel)]="registration.emailId" placeholder="Email"  formControlName="email"></ion-input>
                    </ion-item>

                    <ion-item [class.error]="!userId.valid && userId.touched">
                        <ion-input type="text" placeholder="Username"  [(ngModel)]="registration.userId" formControlName="userId"></ion-input>
                    </ion-item>

                    <!--<ion-item [class.error]="!faculty.valid && faculty.touched">
                        <ion-input type="text" placeholder="Faculty" [(ngModel)]="registration.facultyCode" formControlName="faculty"></ion-input>
                    </ion-item>-->

                    <ion-item>
                        <ion-label>Agreed <span color="primary">Terms & Condition</span></ion-label>
                        <ion-checkbox formControlName="terms"></ion-checkbox>
                    </ion-item>

                </ion-list>

            </ion-card>


            <div *ngIf="name.hasError('required') && name.touched"
                 class="error-box">* {{nameMissing}}
            </div>
            <!--<div *ngIf="!(name.hasError('required')) && name.hasError('pattern') && name.touched"
                 class="error-box">* Name should contain only characters.
            </div>-->
            <div *ngIf="!(name.hasError('required')) && !name.hasError('pattern') && email.hasError('required') && email.touched"
                 class="error-box">* {{emailMissing}}
            </div>
            <div *ngIf="!(name.hasError('required')) && !name.hasError('pattern') && !(email.hasError('required')) && email.hasError('pattern') && email.touched"
                 class="error-box">* {{emailNotValid}}
            </div>
            <div *ngIf="!(name.hasError('required')) && !name.hasError('pattern') && !(email.hasError('required')) && !email.hasError('pattern') &&  userId.hasError('required') && userId.touched"
                 class="error-box">* {{userNameMissing}}
            </div>
            <div *ngIf="!(name.hasError('required')) && !name.hasError('pattern') && !(email.hasError('required')) && !email.hasError('pattern') &&  !userId.hasError('required') && faculty.hasError('required') && faculty.touched"
                 class="error-box">* Please enter faculty code.
            </div>
            <!--<div *ngIf="!(name.hasError('required')) && !name.hasError('pattern') && !(email.hasError('required')) && !(email.hasError('pattern')) &&  !(userId.hasError('required')) && !(faculty.hasError('required')) && !(faculty.hasError('required'))&& !(terms.hasError('required'))&& terms.touched"-->
            <div *ngIf="!(name.hasError('required')) && !name.hasError('pattern') && !(email.hasError('required')) && !(email.hasError('pattern')) &&  !(userId.hasError('required')) && !(terms.hasError('required'))&& terms.touched"

                 class="error-box">* {{termsCondMissing}}
            </div>
            <ion-grid>
                <ion-row>
                    <ion-col>
                        <button ion-button block type="button" (click)="back()">Back</button>
                    </ion-col>
                    <ion-col>
                        <button ion-button block type="submit" (click)="userRegistration()"  [disabled]="!signUpForm.valid">Register</button>
                    </ion-col>
                </ion-row>
            </ion-grid>
        </form>
```

Comment: If ignoring the ionic tags and everything else, what's the important take away?

Comment: dude just read through the code, instead of div tags they used ion-row and ion-col. nothing is different. it's like bootstrap, where you add many class names to style the page but in Ionic you add tags. read through the code

Comment: Not a dude. There are multiple ways to implement forms, this seems to be one of them and I assume it's working well, but it doesn't address the OP question.

Comment: sorry but this is same implementation way which the user's using. my solution may help her to arrive the solution.